# Susy Install Terminal

Tags: terminal, sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I install Susy 1.0.9., also the current version.

I´d like to run a new project by susy version 1.0.9. So I run via Terminal:

```
compass create susy_test -r susy -u susy
```

Thanks for your help.
Ogni

### Terminal

```
og:~ Ogni$ compass create susy_test -r susy -u susy
LoadError on line ["161"] of /Users/Ogni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/compass-0.12.6/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
og:~ Ogni$
```

### My gems

```
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
breakpoint (2.0.7)
bundler (1.6.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
celluloid (0.16.0.pre)
celluloid-io (0.16.0.pre)
chunky_png (1.3.0)
coderay (1.0.9)
compass (1.0.0.alpha.19, 0.12.6)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
compass-validator (3.0.1)
em-websocket (0.5.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
ffi (1.9.3)
formatador (0.2.4)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
guard (2.6.0)
guard-compass (1.1.0)
guard-livereload (2.1.2)
guard-sass (1.4.0)
hitimes (1.2.1)
http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
listen (2.7.1, 1.1.6)
lumberjack (1.0.5)
method_source (0.8.2)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.9.2)
nio4r (1.0.0)
pry (1.0.0.pre1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.3)
rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.3.5, 3.2.19)
singularitygs (1.1.2)
slop (3.5.0)
stitch (0.1.6)
susy (2.1.1, 1.0.9)
thor (0.19.1)
timers (2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to my gemfile:

```
gem "susy", "~> 1.0.9"
```

Now it works

Comment: noob question, but which gemfile do you add this to?